# Determining LVM Extent numbers for given file

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, lvm

I'm currently engaged in a non-work related homework exercise. I have an ext4 filesystem sitting on a logical volume. I'm testing different performance tuning strategies and this idea occurred to me. Since pvmove can move individual and ranges of extents, is there a way to map out what physical extents hold a particular file (in theory it can be backing files for a database, or a large commonly accessed file share) and move them to a particular storage device (for example I have a regular HDD and an SSD drive in the same LVM Volume Group)?

I thought of using "filefrag" but then it occurred to me that I wasn't 100% on whether the extent numbers would necessarily be used in sequential order (so knowing how many sectors in ext4 sees a file isn't necessarily going to let me figure out what which extent numbers/volumes the file is physically sitting on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two main ingredients are `hdparm --fibmap file`, which tells you where the file is physically located within the LV, and `lvs -o +seg_pe_ranges,vg_extent_size` which tells you where the LV is physically located on your device(s).

The rest is math.

So, for example:

```
# hdparm --fibmap linux-3.8.tar.bz2 

linux-3.8.tar.bz2:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 0; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0     288776     298511       9736
     4984832     298520     298623        104
     5038080     298640     298695         56
     5066752     298736     298799         64
     5099520     298824     298895         72
     [...]
```

I don't know why this is so fragmented - downloaded with wget. May be a good example because as you see, you get a headache without scripting this somehow, at least for fragmented files. I'll just take the first segment 288776-298511 (9736 sectors). The count is wrong since it's not 512 byte sectors, but anyhow.

First check that this data is actually correct:

```
# dd if=linux-3.8.tar.bz2 bs=512 skip=0 count=9736 | md5sum
9736+0 records in
9736+0 records out
4984832 bytes (5.0 MB) copied, 0.0506548 s, 98.4 MB/s
7ac1bb05a8c95d10b97982b07aceafa3  -

# dd if=/dev/lvm/src bs=512 skip=288776 count=9736 | md5sum
9736+0 records in
9736+0 records out
4984832 bytes (5.0 MB) copied, 0.123292 s, 40.4 MB/s
7ac1bb05a8c95d10b97982b07aceafa3  -
```

Wheeee.That's identical so we are reading the LV-src at the right place. Now where's the source-LV located?

```
# lvs -o +seg_pe_ranges,vg_extent_size
  LV          VG   Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert PE Ranges             Ext   

[...]
 src         lvm  -wi-ao---   4.00g                                            /dev/dm-1:5920-6047   32.00m
[...]
```

Now that's boring, this LV isn't fragmented. No headache here. Anyway.

It says src is on /dev/dm-1 and starts at PE 5920 and ends at PE 6047. And PE size is 32 MiB.

So lets see if we can read the same thing from /dev/dm-1 directly. Math-wise, this is a little bleargh since we used 512 byte blocksize earlier... :-/ but I'm lazy so I'll just calculate the MiB and then divide by 512! Ha! :-D

```
# dd if=/dev/dm-1 bs=512 skip=$((1024*1024/512 * 32 * 5920 + 288776)) count=9736 | md5sum
9736+0 records in
9736+0 records out
4984832 bytes (5.0 MB) copied, 0.0884709 s, 56.3 MB/s
3858a4cd75b1cf6f52ae2d403b94a685  -
```

Boo-boo. This isn't what we're looking for. What went wrong? Ah! We forgot to add the offset that's occupied by LVM at the beginning of a PV for storing LVM metadata and crap. Usually this is MiB-aligned, so just add another MiB:

```
# dd if=/dev/dm-1 bs=512 skip=$((1024*1024/512 * 32 * 5920 + 288776 + 1024*1024/512)) count=9736 | md5sum
9736+0 records in
9736+0 records out
4984832 bytes (5.0 MB) copied, 0.0107592 s, 463 MB/s
7ac1bb05a8c95d10b97982b07aceafa3  -
```

There you have it.

Comment: Some day they will build statues to your honor.

Comment: One thing though, any idea why [my hdparm invocation is segfaulting](http://dpaste.org/k5Don/)?

Comment: Actually, strike that, [looks like I need to improve on my google-fu](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=892081). It's a new RHEL bug pertaining to SSD's and LVM. I'll take this to mean that file's already on the SSD. Ha

Comment: Is there another utility to determine the file's position in the LV until they fix this?

Comment: You already mentioned it - `filefrag`. Otherwise google if any other tool does fibmap or fiemap.