# How LVM2 works on low level?

Tags: lvm, administration

For example i have two disks with sizes 2 and 4 gb. On each of them i create physical volume of the size of the disk and the combine those physical volumes into volume group and create one logical partition on top of that group.

How the file is gonna be written onto disks in following cases:

- File size < 2GB
- File size = 3GB
- File size ~ 6GB
- File size ~ 4GB

I can't seem to find that information. Most of the links lead to the default tutorials, the closest thing to be called an explanation is on [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/logical_volumes-configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes)

Comment: That entirely depends on how LVM allocates space for the block device, and how the filesystem allocates space for the file. Basically the file can end up "anywhere". You can check experimentally for example [Determining LVM Extent numbers for given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71375/30851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you specifically configure striping when creating the logical volume (and for that you would need physical volumes of identical size), the resulting logical volume (LV for short) will have its blocks 0..(N-1) on the first PV added to the VG, and blocks N..max on the second PV.
(N is the number of blocks available on the first PV after any relevant LVM headers have been applied.)

The way those LV blocks are assigned for files is then decided by the filesystem driver. Unless you configure the filesystem otherwise, it will behave exactly the same as when using a single physical disk that has the same size as the total size of the LV. Different filesystem types may have very different allocation strategies.

Comment: The LVM layout can be seen with `dmsetup table`.